# Multiresolution Images are not rendering properly in WP8

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, screen-resolution

I am developing app in WP8 and I am using two Images according to the screen resolutions. ie. WVGA and WXGA.

I use the scale factor and depending upon that assign two different images. But in WXGA the image gets scaled to 160 scale factor even though I give the WXGA version of my image. Hence the image appears bigger than its original size and gets blurred too. How do I solve this ?How to stop the image scaling when I am already giving scaled image to WXGA?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set the Height and Width for the Image in wvga version and then the layout  will scale to 160%.  On a wxga device , and the image  rendered  on the wxga will not be scaled again.